# Parse custom build rules from Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, makefile

I am currently working on a project to completely revamp the classic "MakeItSo" tool to generate makefiles from a Visual Studio 2010 solution. I am updating it to work with Visual Studio 2015, but it features a different VCProjectEngine whose API is slightly different.

I am trying to extract the custom build rules for each configuration programmatically:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine;

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses one configuration for a custom build rule.
    /// </summary>
    private void parseCustomBuildRule_Configuration(VCFileConfiguration configuration, string relativePath) {
        // We find the custom build rule for this configuration (if there is one)...
        IVCRulePropertyStorage rule = configuration.Tool as IVCRulePropertyStorage;
        if (rule == null)
            return;

        // We will store info about this rule in a CustomBuildRuleInfo_CPP object...
        CustomBuildRule ruleInfo = new CustomBuildRule();
        ruleInfo.RelativePathToFile = relativePath;

        // There is a custom build rule, so we parse it...
        ruleInfo.RuleName = rule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("Name");
        string commandLine = rule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("CommandLine");
```

Unfortunately, rule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("Name") is throwing an exception stating that the property cannot be found. GetUnevaluatedPropertyValue("Name") throws the same error. Even the "CommandLine" property throws an error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I see nothing in your post to indicate this has anything to do with C++ so I have removed the tag.

Comment: VCFileConfiguration stores the file configuration of a C++ project.

Comment: Like I said, C++ has nothing to do with the problem you are having.